# TextInput Placeholder Truncated on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

In iOS the `TextInput` grows in height to fit to contents, but it does not grow to fit a long placeholder. It seems to be limited to two lines and anything longer is truncated with an ellipsis.

Setting the height in the style prop will allow a long placeholder to appear, but that is very imprecise and might not work on all sizes and rotations.

Is there a way to force the `TextInput` on iOS to grow to fit a long placeholder?